# How to Convert C++ sscanf_s() function to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I want to convert following C++ code to C#, but I do not understand what the `sscanf_s` function does in this example or what its C# equivalent is.

```
int         i, Len, iHex;
UCHAR       Buf[20];
CString     sHex;
CString Key = "abc";

Len = Key.GetLength() >> 1; 
for(i = 0; i < Len; i++) {
    sHex = sDesKey.Mid(i * 2, 2);
    sscanf_s(sHex, _T("%x"), &iHex);    
    Buf[i] = ~iHex;             
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code conversion service. Try and do it yourself, and we can help if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: I am sorry but i did't understand about sscanf_s() function.....

Comment: sscanf takes a text string (sHex), and converts it according to a format specification (in this case %x, meaning "the input is hex characters") into one or more values (in this case iHex).  It is turning the two hex characters in sHex into a byte in iHex.

Comment: Also, please don't use single DES for any sort of encryption, and note that C# provides relatively straightforward access to CNG crypto which will be done right.

Comment: Note that the loop expects *pairs* of characters, and a DES key is 64 bits with parity (8 bytes = 16 characters), 56 without (7 bytes, 8 characters).  Triple-DES is three times (or possible twice if you are actually doing 2DES) as long. Even with 3DES, prefer AES - there are some semi-practical attacks against 3DES because the blocksize is so small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the function of `sscanf_s` correctly from Martin Bonner's explanation, you are looking for how to convert a string that represents hexadecimal digits into an `int`. You can do so with the following:

```
iHex = Convert.ToInt32(sHex, 16);
```

This being said, whether or not you want to actually use `int` for your conversion result depends on how you are implementing the rest of that function. (Not all `int`s are created equal across languages.)

Comment: Can you tell me what is following line means..

Buf[i] = ~iHex;

Comment: @Divyesh It means you are taking the [bitwise inversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46zxf1c0(v=vs.100).aspx) of `iHex` and assigning it to the `Buf` array at index `i`.

Comment: Ok...got it....Thank you

Comment: I'd use `ToByte`, but yes.

Comment: @MartinBonner I'd agree. I only used `ToInt32` as the function OP is trying to translate says that `iHex` is of type `int`, so a one to one conversion would necessitate using `int` in C# as well. However, I agree that `int` isn't necessarily the best option for this application, hence the caveat in my answer.